# IOS - como descubro tamanho da tela do aparelho do usuário?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de descobrir o tamanho da tela que o usuário está utilizando ou o modelo de seu iPhone via Objectice-C.

Comment: Resposta aqui. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677716/how-to-get-the-screen-width-and-height-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para descobrir o tamanho da tela em *points*, você pode usar o método `bounds`:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Se você quiser saber o tamanho da tela em *pixels*, você precisa descobrir a *escala* da tela. Por exemplo, os telefones mais antigos terão a escala 1.0, os com a tela retina 2.0, e os maiores (e.g. iPhone 6 Plus) 3.0.

```
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

E depois converter de *points* para *pixels*:

```
CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);
```

[Fonte (do SOen)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779415/751090).